# How to write the code for slider image

Tags: jquery, css

```
    <?php 
             $query1="SELECT * FROM user_photos_offline  WHERE ssmid='$ssmid' AND status='1' ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC LIMIT 0,5";
             $sql=mysql_query($query1); 
             $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);   
             $results=array();
             while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            // $results[]=$row['image'];
            ?>
            <img src="upload_images/<?php echo $row['image']?>" class="img-responsive image" onclick="showImg('upload_images/<?php echo $row['image']?>')">
            <!-- Here i got all images,now it will showing in row by row,but dont want like this,i want i row for and remaining photos are come slider, idont know how to write the code-->
            <?php } ?>
```

Friends ,I want write code for image slider,i dont know how to write the code for slider image,for me no need to plugin,See the below i explained...

Comment: SO is not a coding service, post your attempt if any...

Comment: I was about to say the same ... Plus there is thousand of examples on the Web

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code.

[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi)

```
  @keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

[Updated link](http://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf)

Comment: You have to include both Html and CSS code. Check in the Fiddle.

Comment: Ya its working fine friend,but i want to click next button then only slider should be work,previous button also same

Comment: Try with the Updated link.

Comment: Hope the Updated link worked with you. Let me know if its not working.

Comment: its working,but image has to fetch in database,how it will be work,same code i am using,i change little bit .i am writing like this

Comment: Please see this link,i am writing like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941885/how-to-write-the-style-for-slider-image